# CMD and set /p while looking for an IP

Tags: cmd

I have a little program for a test that will be put in my big program.

So I want to enter a IP address into a set /p var= varible but it can only be numbers. Not letter. i.e if I were to enter facebook.com it would throw an error i.e echo Invaild and pause

So if I enter a IP in the IP structer 192.168.1.4 it will echo Valid. but if I enter a bunch of numbers like 544564212.545 not in the IP structer it will call the error lable/ marker thing (:marker) and echo Invaild. SO it must only work on a IP structer string.

Thanks you guys for all your help. My program will be availble in a few days. Thanks you agian for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set /p var=Enter IP address: 
set var=%var: =%
echo %var%|findstr /rc:"^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$" >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo Valid IP address.
) else (
  echo Not a valid IP address.
)
```

Comment: Thanks again but is there a way to make it not echo the IP address varible when using the findstr command

Comment: It says, `1922.168.1.4` is valid.

Comment: @mfm4aa Because the pattern only checks if the string consists of 4 dot-separated numbers. I could change the expression to match 1-3 digits per group, but even then you could enter invald addresses (e.g. `256.168.1.4`). If you wanted a more accurate validation, you'd have to split the string and check if the numeric value of each substring were between 1 and 255.

Comment: I wouldn't know, since I can't see what changes you made to the above code sample (which doesn't produce such an error).

Comment: Now I am talking about this @echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=%~1"
set "flag="

for /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%i in ("%var%") do set /a var1=%%i, var2=%%j, var3=%%k, var4=%%l
for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if %%i neq 1 (set "var0=!var0!.!var%%i!") else set "var0=!var%%i!"
for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if "!var%%i!" equ "" set "flag=1"
if not defined flag for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if !var%%i! lss 0 set "flag=1"
if not defined flag for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if !var%%i! gtr 255 set "flag=1"
if defined flag (echo "%var0%" is NOT a valid IP.) else echo "%var0%" is a valid IP.
endlocal

Answer (score 0):

I made a slightly more complex script. You shoud call it from the command line: `<script.cmd> IP`, eg. `<script.cmd> 192.168.1.4`.

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=%~1"
set "flag="

for /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%i in ("%var%") do set /a var1=%%i, var2=%%j, var3=%%k, var4=%%l
for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if %%i neq 1 (set "var0=!var0!.!var%%i!") else set "var0=!var%%i!"
for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if "!var%%i!" equ "" set "flag=1"
if not defined flag for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if !var%%i! lss 0 set "flag=1"
if not defined flag for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do if !var%%i! gtr 255 set "flag=1"
if defined flag (echo "%var0%" is NOT a valid IP.) else echo "%var0%" is a valid IP.
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks but which varible stores the IP address i.e 192.168.1.4

Comment: It says, `1.23.0.42` is invalid.

Comment: Yes. I changed the code: the first octet must be greater than zero, the others can be equal to zero. The IP address is stored in `var0`.

Comment: The netblock `0.0.0.0/8` may be IANA-reserved, but the addresses in it are still valid.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Changed the script. :)